# I'm trying to call a function from different UIViewController through protocol, but I'm getting nil on delegate - what might be the case here?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I have two UIViewControllers.

The first one contains a container that is visible by default, the class looks something like this:

```
protocol HandleMapPopupBehavior {
    func hideContainer()
}

class MapEvents: UIViewController, HandleMapPopupBehavior {

@IBOutlet weak var userDetails: UIView!    

var userProfile: YourFullUser?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userProfile = YourFullUser()
}

func hideContainer(){
    userDetails.hidden = true
    print("hiding container now")
}

}
```

The second one contains a call that should invoke the function `hideContainer()` in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
class YourFullUser: UIViewController{

var delegate: HandleMapPopupBehavior?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    delegate!.hideContainer() //this line causes error
    print("container should be hidden")
}
```

But now when I run this ViewController I'm getting error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What might be the case here?

Comment: You never set delegate to anything. Therefore it is nil. You then added ! which forces an unwrap of a nil value.

Comment: Add the line `userProfile.delegate = self` and you should be able to fix it. There's no reason to implicitly unwrap the delegate though. And use a weak reference to your delegate to prevent a reference cycle.

Comment: @Eendje what do you exactly mean by weak reference? Could you please post it as an answer so that I could accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your protocol conform to `class`

```
protocol HandleMapPopupBehavior: class {
    func hideContainer()
}
```

When you create `YourFullUser` assign `self` to it's delegate:

```
class MapEvents: UIViewController, HandleMapPopupBehavior {

    var userProfile: YourFullUser?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userProfile = YourFullUser()
        userProfile?.delegate = self
    }

    func hideContainer() {
        print("hiding container now")
    }
}
```

YourFullUser class:

```
class YourFullUser: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: HandleMapPopupBehavior?

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        delegate?.hideContainer() // Safely use the delegate
    }
}
```

Comment: I tired your solution but it didn't work, unfortunately. I'm not getting any error, but also I don't see the `hiding container now`. I added this block right before the `delegate?.hideContainer()`: `if ( delegate == nil){
            print("delegate is empty")
        }` and I see this message in my console, so that's the problem - how can I 'fill' (initialize) the delegate object?

Comment: Did you add `userProfile?.delegate = self` when you create `YourFullUser()`? Because without assigning the delegate, it will obviously be `nil`. :)

Comment: yes I did :) I even tried to move it from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`, but the result is the same :(

Comment: One thought that I have now - my class `MapEvents` also conform to another class: `class MapEvents: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster, HandleMapPopupBehavior {`, so maybe when I do `userProfile?.delegate = self` then it gets confused and does not assign the proper value. Is there a way of setting the delegate to the specific class (in my case `HandleMapPopupBehavior`) instead of `ContainerToMaster`?

Comment: I don't know where and how you're using the class. If you have the time, it could be useful to add it to the question. But for now you can also try to add an initializer to `YourFullUser` class and set the delegate directly in there, e.g. `init(delegate: HandleMapPopupBehavior) { self.delegate = delegate }`

Comment: I removed the second protocol just for tests and your soultion worked, so I will accept your answer now and ask another question regarding delegating from two protocols :) Thanks!